# Is vuforia free or needs Premium account to use in commercial products

Tags: android, vuforia

am new one to Augmented reality, Here i need to know the Vuforia sdk is free or cost to use in my commercial products,If it free means what is the restriction to use this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vuforia SDKs are all free, there are no licensing fees.But there are some restrictions on redistribution and sublicensing of the libraries.

see this forum discussion on this,

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/general-discussion/use-vuforia-my-commercial-product-free-cost.

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/qcar-api/commercial-use-modified-vuforia-sample-code

Comment: Can i use it in my commercial product for my client

Comment: @mohan: Yes you can, but read the SDK license to see what obligations that entails.